# Flag > Should be closed > Off-topic > Belongs on another SE site > Meta or ELL; but no other option

Tags: support, status-bydesign

Why does form not offer "other" or sumsuch option when flagging a Question for a mod to move?

So I choose "unclear what you are asking", if it's not obvious how a question about Latin inflection relates to English. That's not the problem. It's just that I keep looking for a minute whether my mobile display is hiding the missing option.

Answer (score 3):

It's true that for users with less than 3000 rep (or 500 on beta sites), "Other" is not available as an option for a **flag,** whereas it **is** a close-vote option above the rep threshold. The only people who can deal with "other" flags are moderators, so you need to use the "moderator attention" reason. There aren't usually two routes provided to a particular action. Flags are dealt with by moderators (on the whole), so since you can't vote to migrate you can only ask moderators to have a look at the question.

However, once you gain the reputation to vote to close questions (rather than merely flag), you do get the "Other" option and can write in a reason.

> Questions should be closed by casting close votes if:
>
> - they are sufficiently similar to existing questions and would be answered identically to them.
> - they are unclear, too broad, or otherwise problematic to identifying the problem in a way that can be properly addressed by answerers
> - they are sufficiently off-topic, as outlined in the help center.
>
> Note that once you gain the reputation to vote to close, you should no longer flag for moderator attention to have questions closed or migrated. It is your responsibility to vote now. See also: [How should my flagging change when I gain the ability to vote to close?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3154/how-should-my-flagging-change-when-i-gain-the-ability-to-vote-to-close)

That implies that if you cannot vote to close, you should flag for moderator attention instead. That should offer you a write-in box for your reason for flagging: please be as specific as possible. Note that even the full vote-to-close options do not include any other sites except ELL and Meta.ELU, so if you believe a question should go to a different site you will still need to raise a flag.

Comment: That does not answer the question. Is the lack of options intended with the consequent need to verbalize a reason under *other reasons*; Why? Or is it a mistake. Is it perhaps purposeful, yet a mistake?

Comment: "Other" is not available in the low-rep flagging options. It's awarded with the close-vote privilege. It's not a mistake: it's the way the system works.

Comment: This has nothing to do with low rep, as you noted yourself.

Comment: It **is** to do with low reputation, as you will find the options change when you reach the rep threshold for that to happen. Low-rep users cannot vote to close; and the flagging does not contain an "other" option because the only people who can deal with "other" flags are moderators, so you need to use the "moderator attention" reason. I suppose I could add that to the answer...

Comment: the form for mod attention to move a Q could be filled automatically if only the option was shown where it makes sense, which I described. I suppose it

Comment: the form for mod attention to move a Q could be filled automatically if only the option was shown where it makes sense, which I described. I suppose the way it is discourages random selection of the board to be moving to.